# Create a web interface for a user to easily create teams from the available players list

Tags: javascript, json

Visually indicate which players are ACTIVE and which are INACTIVE

Display 3 Teams with empty roster slots (Team 1, Team 2, and Team 3)

Allow user to drag ACTIVE Players onto Teams

Data source: http://s3.amazonaws.com/dii-test/data.json

Comment: so you expect us to do your homework for free?

Answer (score 0):

> Visually indicate which players are ACTIVE and which are INACTIVE

CSS [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

> Display 3 Teams with empty roster slots (Team 1, Team 2, and Team 3)

`div` elements with min dimensions

> Allow user to drag ACTIVE Players onto Teams

HTML [drag and drop](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_draganddrop.asp)